# VB.Net - Reminder - Startup

Tags: windows, vb.net, startup

I have designed an application and I want this to run When ever I turn on my lap on and should execute some reminders which I have configured. I also need a "Snooze" and "Completed" button on the reminder. I want it to remind me for every 1 hour till I click "Finish" Button on the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Use Task Scheduler Service to schedule tasks.

For Visual Basic 6 you should use Task Scheduler Scripting Objects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx